# Is Redisson map thread-safe?

Tags: redis, redisson

I have 8 Storm Bolt-Executors running in parallel.
I have a stats cache : Map>

e.g. userVisitCache -> ( userId, (roomId, totalVisit)) 
any of the 8 parallel threads (Bolt Executor) , whenever finds an user in a room will increment the count and if finds outside room will decrement the count.

Now my question if I use Redisson ,  then is  `userVisitCache.get(userId).put(roomId, visitCount)` 
threadsafe ?

If not, then should I use userVisitCache.getLock().lock() .. to lock the cache ?
In that case, should I use Redisson Read-Write Lock or just usual cache.getLock() ?

Answer (score 2):

All Redisson objects including Map are fully thread-safe.